# Print objects and arrays in console log dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building a logger service. First argument is "msg" string and the second one in array of parameters (can be array or objects)
How can i iterate this parameters array and print in the console so the object/array can be seen\expand\collapse in the console?

For example if it's not dynamic i would do something like this:

```
console.log('str', obj1, obj2, obj3)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```js
    let arrayOfObjects = [
      { a: 1, b: 2 },
      { a: 3, b: 4, c: 5 }
    ];
    let testMessage = "This is just a message";
    
    console.log(testMessage, Object.values(arrayOfObjects));
```